# Angular HTTP problems

Tags: angular, http

The problem is - that i don't realy know how to correctly use HTTP services to get and show profile info in my angular app.
Here is my user-profile-component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { UserService } from '../user.service';
import { userInfo} from '../shared/users_class';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-user-profile',
 templateUrl: './user-profile.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./user-profile.component.css']
})


export class UserProfileComponent implements OnInit {
 id:number;
 userInfo:userInfo;

 constructor(private router: ActivatedRoute, private userService:UserService) { }

 ngOnInit() {

 this.router.paramMap.subscribe(params=>{
  this.id = +params.get("id");
 });

  this.userService.getUserInfoFromDB(this.id).subscribe(data=>{
   console.log(data);
   this.userInfo = new userInfo(data.phone,
     data.marriage_status,
     data.city_birth, 
     data.current_city,
     data.sex
   );
  });
 }
}
```

My user-http-service function:

```
getUserInfoFromDB(user_id) {
    return this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/user_info/'+ user_id)
                    .catch((error:any) =>{return Observable.throw(error);});;
}
```

My JSON - respone from server:

```
{
"id": 4,
"phone": "123456789",
"marriage_status": 0,
"date_birth": "1997-01-23",
"city_birth": "someCity",
"current_city": "someCurrCity",
"sex": "M",
"user": 3
}
```

and the [error_message here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orFMc.png)

My view:

```
<div *ngIf="userInfo.date_birth">
  date_birth: {{userInfo.date_birth}}
</div><br>
<div *ngIf="userInfo.curr_city">
  curr_city: {{userInfo.curr_city}}
</div><br>
<div *ngIf="userInfo.phone">
  phone: {{userInfo.phone}}
</div><br>
```

Comment: Then read the documentation ? https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

this code here is not a god practice

```
getUserInfoFromDB(user_id) {
    return this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/user_info/'+ user_id)
                    .catch((error:any) =>{return Observable.throw(error);});;
}
```

inside the catch method the idea is handle the error not throw a new one.

if your are using the HttpCLient class then the data is already converted into json if yoru are Using the HTTP class to execute the request then you need to parse the data that comes in the response

is better if your use observables every where and let the view handle the observable

```
userInfo: Observable<userInfo>

   this.userInfo = this.userService.getUserInfoFromDB(this.id).map(data=>{
return new userInfo(data.phone,
     data.marriage_status,
     data.city_birth, 
     data.current_city,
     data.sex
   );
  });
 }
```

your view will look like

```
<div *ngIf="(userInfo | async); let user">
  date_birth: {{user.date_birth}}
</div><br>
<div *ngIf="user.curr_city">
  curr_city: {{user.curr_city}}
</div><br>
<div *ngIf="user.phone">
  phone: {{user.phone}}
</div><br>
```

***how to get the value from the route***

```
this.userInfo = this.router.paramMap.flatMap(params=>{
return this.userService.getUserInfoFromDB(params.get("id")).map(data=>{
return new userInfo(data.phone,
     data.marriage_status,
     data.city_birth, 
     data.current_city,
     data.sex
   );
  });
 });
```

Comment: this still wont be fully functional, as you are synchronously accessing this.id at component level

Comment: @Jota.Toledo you can flatMap from the route service  and pass the id that comes

Comment: what is the purpose of using paramMap as source stream and not use the value emited by it in the flatMap operation? You are still accessing this.id

Comment: @Jota.Toledo sorry my bad, I will fix the code, (copy and paste issue)